# Tomcat not redeploying after local change

Tags: tomcat, deployment, war

I am having an issue I don't seem to find the asnwer to.

I have deployed a webapp using a war file, and I can see it fine through my local host, however when I do local changes, these changes do not show up.

What can I do so that my local files sync up with the expanded war file directory and I can see local changes in my localhost?

Comment: Which IDE are you using to do the local changes?

Comment: activate `deploy on save` property in your IDE.